# Operations on stacks of coins

Tags: algorithms

I'm struggling with a problem from some old programming contest with no result, so I'm asking for help here. Let me describe it below.

At first we have $1\le n\le1000$ stacks of coins, each of them contains at most $10^9$ coins. Then in one move we select the highest stack (if there are many with maximal number of coins, we select one of them) and let's say that it has $m$ coins. Then we split it into two stacks containing $m$ div 2 and ($m$+1) div 2 coins respectively. We make moves until there are only stacks with $1$ coin.

So the input for this problem is a number $n$ and then $n$ numbers describing initial heights of those stacks. Then there is a number $1\le q\le 5*10^5$ which denotes number of queries. Each query consists of one number $1\le k\le 10^9$. So we have $q$ queries, respectively: $k_1, k_2,..., k_q$ and we know that the sum of those numbers is less or equal the number of possible moves until end condition. For number $k_1$ we have to print the number of different heights of stacks after $k_1$ moves. For number $k_2$ we have to print the number of different heights of stacks after **next** $k_2$ moves, and so on.

This problem would be easy if it wasn't for possible big initial heights of stacks ($10^9$).

For **example**, we have $3$ stacks with $9, 2$ and $8$ coins respectively, at first. Then for query input (first number is a number q): $3, 1, 2, 3$, the correct output is: $4, 3, 2$, because after first move we have stacks: $8,5,4,2$, after three moves we have: $4,4,4,3,2$ (three different heights), and after $1+2+3=6$ moves we have: $3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2$.

Can anybody help? How can I solve this fast? (standard time limit 1sec for one test file and 256MB RAM, something like $O(q\log q)$ should be fine).

Comment: SPOJ problem? (It looks like one, I don't claim it is)

Comment: Sure it looks like one, like every problem from programming contest. But this one I found in some old book.

Comment: Is there something wrong with actually running the moves on a map from column size to number of columns of that size?

Comment: @KarolisJuodele Also thought about that, but a proof that the number of columns of different size is nicely bounded by above would be nice(naively it is $10^9$, but improvements can be made)

Comment: Yes, that approach fails for that possible big (10^9) initial heights of stacks. We can both run out of memory and time limit. The number of moves is tooo big with those constraints. Even with some optimizations (perform all moves for all highest columns in one) it's not nearly good enough. I think it requires some smart observation.

Comment: The total number of moves is at most $n\log_2{10^9}=9n\log_2{10}$, it is not *that* big.

Comment: $9n\log 10$ is very small. Unfortunately that is not the bound for the number of moves. You calculated depth of some tree, and each move is a branch in that tree.

Comment: True, I got confused. Using an hybrid approach of Karolis' suggestion, we can actually fit in $256$MB. But if the problem is processing I am out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

Up to order of operations, the *way* a particular stack is split is independent from the others.

> **Theorem:** At every step, each one of the original stacks has at most $3$ different children.

**Proof:** Denote $[y]$ to be a stack of $y$ coins, $
\xrightarrow{N}$ to be $N$ iterations of the algorithm(if $N$ is missing assume one iteration) and $*$ to be an arbirtary number.

Setting $k=2^m(2n+1)$ to be the amout of coins in a particular stack, we have
$$[2^m(2n+1)] \rightarrow 2[2^{m-1}(2n+1)]\rightarrow2[2^{m-2}(2n+1)],[2^{m-1}(2n+1)]$$
$$\rightarrow4[2^{m-2}(2n+1)]$$
By induction we can verify that at every step there are at most $2$ different children, and that
$$[2^m(2n+1)] \xrightarrow{2^{m}-1} 2^m[2n+1]\tag1$$
So we have $2^m$ equal stacks of $2n+1$ coins each. Analyzing only one of them:
$$[2n+1]\rightarrow[n],[n+1]$$
If $n=2q$
$$[2q],[2q+1]\rightarrow[2q],[q+1],[q]\rightarrow 3[q],[q+1]$$
$$\implies a[2q],b[2q+1]\xrightarrow{a+b} (2a+b)[q],b[q+1]\tag2$$
If $n=2q+1$
$$[2q+1],[2q+2]\rightarrow[2q+1],2[q+1]\rightarrow [q],3[q+1]$$
$$\implies a[2q+1],b[2q+2]\xrightarrow{a+b} a[q],(a+2b)[q+1]\tag3$$
So in general $a[x],b[x+1]\xrightarrow{*}c[y],d[y+1]$, where $x>y$(we can deal with the case $a[1],b[2]$ easily) and at every step there is at most three diferent stacks.

**Conclusion:** Processes $(1),(2),(3)$, are *immediate*, that is, they can be done consecutively without switching our attention to other stacks(why?), allowing us to apply all those iterations at once (becomes especially useful when the coefficients $a,b$ get large). Therefore we can just massively jump those intermediate steps with $3$ different stacks. Anyway, depending on the query we are given we may stop mid-process. Finally, it would suffice to create a data structure for each of the stacks so that it can hold integers $a,b,c,x,y,z$ to represent $a[x],b[y],c[z]$.